# Agglomerative clustering with must-link constraints

Tags: python, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

How can implement Agglomerative clustering be implemented to support [must-link constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_clustering)?

I have seen the [scikit-learn clustering toolkit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering) interesting, but it seems that scikit-learn only supports constraints of the form of not using certain neighboring edges to create the cluster, but not more global constraints. Solutions that don't use scikit-learn can also be interesting.

Comment: How do you see the must-link constraint specified along with the input data (which is a distance matrix in agglomerative clustering)? Is that a categorical variable labeling by the same code objects that must be "gathered" together in the same cluster? Or is it some binary matrix alongside the distance matrix?

Comment: For my case, I have a set of some samples that I don't want either of them to fall in the same cluster?

Comment: Well, you could simply set their pairwise distance to a supervalue (knowingly too large distance). Then use linkage method that will be sensitive to it, i.e., don't use nearest neighbour method, for example.

Comment: Oh... That's a good solution. I thought the distance needed to have properties such as the triangle inequality.

Comment: Triangle inequality is important for points which potentially are expected to unite in one cluster sooner or later. Setting one of the three distances to an extremely large magnitude ruins it, which is not bad.

Comment: Our aim is to make computed distance between cluster A (containing point x) and cluster B (containing point y) intolerably large if the x-y distance is the very large value. And since we are not going to recognize or let the A-B merge, we are not bothered whether triangular inequality holds or not - between all points belonging to these different clusters (i.e. some one point in A, the other two in B, or vice versa).

Comment: It is informally allowable to imagine the x-y super-distance in the triplet x,y,z as not straight but "zigzagged" or a loop extended into an extra "dimension".

Answer (score 0):

In the usual, uncontrained case, hierarchical agglomerative clustering starts with every point assigned to its own cluster. On each iteration, we select two clusters to merge, according to some chosen criterion. Merging continues until a stopping condition is met.

One simple way to impose must-link constraints would be to introduce them during initialization. Start with each point in its own cluster, then merge clusters containing points that must link. Then, continue merging clusters as usual. Since clusters can only be merged and never split, the must-link constraints will remain satisfied.

Comment: Imposing this obligatory merge from the very beginning is problematic. Say, x and y are "must link" points, but the distance x-y is greater than the unconstrained x-z distance (which might even be clise to 0). Now, merging (x,y) can make it difficult to merge this pair with z later.

Comment: I think the only fully unproblematic setting of must-link constraint is when there are "preexisting clusters", that is, the input is distance matrix between points plus _one_ categorical variable showing which pre-existing cluster which point belongs to. Then we simply start the analysis treating the pre-existing clusters as different datasets: we first agglomerate inside of them, only after it we go on agglomerating among them.